# Present UIViewController from subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have created a subclass of `UIView`, Now in my app i need to present a `UIViewController` from it,

I have tried following :

```
poiInfoController = [[poiInfoController alloc]initWithNibName:@"poiInfoController" bundle:nil];
[poiInfoController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:poiInfoController animated:YES];
```

but it will crash with **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'**

Please Help,

```
**EDIT CRASH LOG:**

2014-04-23 17:04:26.433 NavigationLibSprintMoM[4610:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <ViewController: 0x9d52140>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017c15e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d08b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x0036217a -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4879
    3   UIKit                               0x00362caf -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    4   NavigationLibSprintMoM              0x00005f7b -[NavigationView handleGesture:] + 964
    5   UIKit                               0x005baf8c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 230
    6   UIKit                               0x005b9c00 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 383
    7   UIKit                               0x005bb66d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    8   UIKit                               0x005bebcd ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 57
    9   UIKit                               0x005beb4e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    10  UIKit                               0x005b5248 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 199
    11  UIKit                               0x00281d4a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    12  UIKit                               0x00282c6a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    13  UIKit                               0x00256a36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    14  UIKit                               0x00240d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0174a8af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0174a23b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0176730e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01766b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0176694b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x038699d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x038697fe GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x0024394b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  NavigationLibSprintMoM              0x0000374d main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01f54725 start + 0
    25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Could you paste the complete exception raised?

Comment: It appears you are attempting to display the view of `poiInfoController` twice... Is there an instance of it anywhere else? (Also does your ivar really have the same name as its class?)

Comment: @NSBum: I have recheck code there is only one  `poiInfoController` is presented, is there something else ?? 

it would be great if you tell some other method for presenting viewcontroller.

Comment: presentViewController:animated:completion

Comment: @elio.d: i have also try with this, but it will gives same error, please help

Comment: You have a class called ViewController? because it seems that you are trying to present twice the same instance of this class

Comment: From a style perspective it's the _ViewController_ that should be controlling view changes.

Comment: I add a similar issue lately, the following "fixed" it :
1) init your view controller
2) add the view of your view controller as subview of the current window
3) init a nav controller setting the view controller you want to open as root view controller
4) present the view controller

Comment: probabaly something wrong with your navigation stack, as the Apple docs says: _Any view controller object can present a single view controller at a time._, please read more about how the navigation stack can be built up with modal views: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html